# Django dynamic header for global variable

Tags: django

Is there any way I can use dynamic header and footer?

In my project so that I can define global variable also dynamic variable data per page.

```
    <body>
    <header>
        <My dynamic header template>
    </header>
    <content>
      <Page template>
    <content>

    <footer>
     <My dynamic footer template>
    <footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Include method to solve your problem like this

```
{% include "Template_path" with title_pager="title_path" %}
```

title_path: title of your path if required
template_path: path for your template file
This will solve your problem by providing dynamic template_path according to your requirement.